# Deleting a Tkinter button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Whenever I use the destroy() function to delete a button in tkinter all the other widgets in the tkinter gui window below that button shift up creating a gap at the bottom of my screen. I don't want this to happen. Is there any way of preventing the widgets from shifting after deletion of the button? Also note that i have to put the buttons in a label which is put in a frame and that frame is in the main gui window. These are the constraints.

`enter code here`

```
from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()
screen.title("Kaun Banega Crorepati - The Game")
screen.geometry('1920x1080+0+0')
gameframe = Frame(screen, bg='#2e004d',width=1920,height=1080)
gameframe.pack()
panel = Label(gameframe, bg='#2e004d', width=1920, height=1080)
panel.pack()

def cmd():
    optionc.destroy()


optiona = Button(panel, text='A.option', font='Arial 18 bold', bg='black', 
fg='yellow')
optiona.pack(side='top', padx=40,pady=20)

optionb = Button(panel, text='B.option', font='Arial 18 bold', bg='black', 
fg='yellow')
optionb.pack(side='top', padx=40,pady=20)

optionc = Button(panel, text='C.option', font='Arial 18 bold', bg='black', 
fg='yellow')
optionc.pack(side='top', padx=40,pady=20)

optiond = Button(panel, text='D.option', font='Arial 18 bold', bg='black', 
fg='yellow')
optiond.pack(side='top', padx=40,pady=20)

destroybutton=Button(panel,text='destroy',font='Arial 18 bold', bg='black', 
fg='yellow',border=5,command=cmd)
destroybutton.pack(side='top', padx=40,pady=20)


screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: preventing the widgets from shifting after deletion of a button

Instead of using **Pack Geometry Manager**, which is dynamic, use **Place Geometry Manager**.

**Core Point**:

```
.place(x=..., y=...)
```

[image] [image]

---

**Reference**:

- [The Tkinter Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)

  > Allows you explicitly set the position and size of widgets, either in absolute terms, or relative to another widget.

---

**Note**: I recommend to use `tk.Frame` as the container, but you can also change to `tk.Label`.

Define the `FixedPanel(tk.Frame)` container class.
Extend with:

- `button=`: A seq of `tuple(text, command)`
- `def button(text)`: Returns the reference to the `Button` that matches `text`.

```
import tkinter as tk


class FixedPanel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        items = kwargs.pop('button', None)
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        for n, (text, command) in enumerate(items):
            button = tk.Button(self, text=text, command=command,
                               font='Arial 18 bold', bg='black', fg='yellow')
            button.place(x=20, y=(n * 60) + 20)

    def button(self, text):
        for child in list(self.children):
            button = self.nametowidget(child)
            if button['text'] == text:
                return button
```

**Usage**:

Use the `class FixedPanel` as any other `tkinter` widget.
To `.destroy()` a `Button`, get the reference of the `Button` using `panel.button(<text>)`

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Kaun Banega Crorepati - The Game")
        self.geometry('800x500+0+0')

        self.panel = FixedPanel(self, bg='red', width=170, height=350,
                                button=(('A.option', None),
                                        ('B.option', None),
                                        ('C.option', None),
                                        ('D.option', None),
                                        ('destroy', self.cmd))
                                )
        self.panel.pack()

    def cmd(self):
        self.panel.button('C.option').destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: i understand your point but the pack and place geometry managers don't work together. i have already written around 1000 lines of code for this project and and used the pack manager. So is there a way of doing this with pack geometry manager.

Comment: ***"pack and place geometry managers don't work together"***: This restriction belongs if used on the **same** parent container widget. All inside `class FixedPanel` is independant from outside. The object `panel` are layouted using `self.panel.pack()`.

Comment: @alok Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)